# Change style and format of tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code that is supposed to update the style of the tables in a Word document and then change the width to 17cm.

```
Sub ConvertTables()

    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Style = "K2 Table"
    Next

    Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    Selection.Tables(1).PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(17)
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, it stops at the second part. Sometimes it will run in the VB viewer but never from running the macro through the Developer.

What is wrong with this piece of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim tbl As Table
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    tbl.Style = "K2 Table"

    tbl.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    tbl.PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(17)        
Next
```

I'm guessing the second part doesn't work when you don't have a table selected